# Проблема с подключением к удалённому ПК

Tags: c#

Имеется следующий код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string username = @"Abserv\r.ivanov"; // Нужно чтобы соединялось и через домен и без.
            string password = @"Blab";
            string network_file_path = @"\\172.10.0.80\c$\test\test.txt";
            string local_file_path = @"c:\test\test.txt";
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
            WindowsIdentity idnt = new WindowsIdentity(username, password);
            WindowsImpersonationContext context = idnt.Impersonate();
            File.Copy(network_file_path, local_file_path, true);
            context.Undo();
        }
    }
}
```

Однако при выполнении данного кода возникает ошибка «Указанное имя не является корректным»:

[image: Снимок окна консоли с текстом ошибки]

Что является причиной данной проблемы?

Comment: Отформатируйте, пожалуйста, код. Ваш вопрос нечитаем.

Comment: Каталог `c:\test\` существует?

Comment: Да существует(((

Comment: Что-то на msdn [пример](//msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) куда сложнее.

Comment: @ИванНечкин, а не должен же?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517026/178988 - дубликат

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он [задан повторно](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517026/178988) под другим пользователем (который тоже не зарегистрирован). Вероятно, этот пользователь [больше не существует](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2689/178988), поэтому закрывать следует этот вопрос, а не тот. @ИванНечкин, если этот пользователь ещё существует, а тот вопрос не твой, напиши об этом в комментарии.

Answer (score 3):

Второй параметр [WindowsIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dsd0tkz(v=vs.110).aspx) - это не пароль.
Посмотрите [пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Не понятно пока(