# Удалённое подключение и копирование

Tags: c#

Проблема: есть локальная сеть, а в ней ПК, у которого я знаю: домен, пароль, имя пользователя и IP. Надо с него удалённо скопировать файл из известной директории на свой компьютер.
Подскажите, как и через что это можно организовать?

Comment: Хм, а каталог, откуда вы собираетесь копировать, открыт как share?

Comment: @VladD http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516870/178988 Но отвечать лучше тут, т. к. пользователь не зарегистрирован и тот, вероятно, уже не существует.